# Postgres flyway COPY from CSV file

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to run a `COPY` command from Flyway migration script to load csv file against PostgreSQL DB in a Spring Boot Project. I am getting the below error on this.

```
SQL State  : 58P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: could not open file "./scripts/test.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
  Hint: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
Location   : db/migration/V1.0.83__test.sql
Line       : 18
Statement  : COPY public.table1(type, code, prefix) FROM './scripts/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

I have kept the csv file under resources/db/migration/script folder in Spring-Boot project.

Is there anyway i can achieve this? Appreciate any help?